# Método en python que tome una matriz de letras consecutivas (crecientes) como entrada y que devuelva la letra que falta en la matriz

Tags: python

requisitos: 
Siempre obtendrá una matriz válida. Y siempre faltará exactamente una letra. La longitud de la matriz siempre será al menos 2.
La matriz siempre contendrá letras en un solo caso.
¡Usa el alfabeto inglés con 26 letras!)

ejemplo:

["a","b","c","d","f"] -> "e"

["O","Q","R","S"] -> "P"

Estoy intentando hacerlo pero no encuentro la forma de mostrar la letra faltante.

```
 def Alfhabet(chars):
    lista=list("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")
    #lista2= list("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")
    y= []
    for i in lista:
        if i not in chars:
            y.append(i)
             del(lista[:])
    return y

print(Alfhabet(["a","b","c","d","f"]))
print(Alfhabet(["O","Q","R","S"])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que encontrar el índice de la primera letra de la lista en el "abcedario", luego iteras a la par sobre la lista y el "abecedario" y retornar la letra del "abecedario" en el momento que no coincida con la de la lista.

Creo que una opción mucho más simple es usar `ord` para obtener el valor entero que representa al carácter (code-point Unicode) y su inverso `chr` para pasar el valor entero a su carácter correspondiente. Con ello te evitas tener que lidiar con si la lista contiene mayúsculas o minúsculas:

```
def alfhabet(chars):
    primera = ord(chars[0])
    for letra in chars:
        if (siguiente := chr(primera)) != letra:
            return siguiente
        primera +=1
```

> ```
> >>> print(alfhabet(["a","b","c","d","f"]))
> e
> >>> print(alfhabet(["O","Q","R","S"]))
> P
> ```

Ten en cuenta que los 26 caracteres del alfabeto inglés tienen code-points consecutivos, tanto las mayúsculas (65 - 90) como las minúsculas (97- 122) heredados de ASCII.

Los únicos requisitos de la función es que la lista de entrada esté ordenada (si éste no fuera el caso, podemos recurrir a `sorted()`) y que todas sean minúsculas o mayúsculas. Que falten o no una letra no importa, si no falta retorna `None`.

Una versión extendida que solo requiere que todas sean mayúsculas o minúsculas sería:

```
def alfhabet(chars):
    chars = sorted(chars)
    faltan = []
    primera = ord(chars[0])
    for letra in chars:
        if (siguiente := chr(primera)) != letra:
            faltan.append(siguiente) 
            primera += 1
        primera +=1
    return faltan
```

> ```
> >>> print(alfhabet(["a","b","d","f"]))
> ['c', 'e']
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Otra forma de hacerlo es haciendo un slice de una lista madre `['A', 'B'..., 'y', 'z']` desde el primer elemento de la lista dada `chars[0]` hasta el último de misma `chars[-1]`.
Se convierten ambas listas a [set()](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) y se devuelve una lista con la diferencia entre el sliced y el set de la lista provista por el usuario. Esta función puede calcular y retornar todos los elementos que faltan, no solo 1.

```
def Alfhabet(chars):
    abc = list(chr(x) for x in range(65, 123) if(x<91 or x>96))
    idx0 = abc.index(chars[0])
    idx1 = abc.index(chars[-1])
    return list(set(abc[idx0 : idx1]) - set(chars))
```

La salida es una lista, pero se puede convertir a cadena:

```
print(Alfhabet(["a","b","c","d","f"]))
# ['e']
y = Alfhabet(["O","R","S"]) # En este ejemplo faltan 2 caracteres
print(', '.join(str(x) for x in y))
# P, Q
```

Answer (score 0):

Para tipo de problemas lo mejor es usar una solución recursiva:

```py
def alphabet(chars):
   expected = chr(ord(chars[0]) + 1)
   return expected if chars[1] != expected else alphabet(chars[1:])
```

Otra solución todavía más compacta:

```py
def alphabet(chars):
   return next(y for (x,y) in zip(chars,chars[1:]) if ord(x)+1!=ord(y))
```